# Can't get menu working the way I would like to in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, menu, breadcrumbs

My apologies up-front, as I've asked this question already on Doctype.com, but figure that this site is more appropriate. I've been trying to wrap my head around Drupal's menu system, with little progress. I've just started working with Drupal having come from using DotNetNuke.  Please, please, please help me understand this! The website has some backend functionality for authenticated users, and the following menu hierarchy resembles what the public-facing menu should look like:

---

- Home
- About Us
- Services

  - Counselling
  - Career Guidance
- News

  - Chairman's Speeches
  - Community News
  - Gallery
- Contact Us

---

Before I continue, let me say that every item above is associated with a node of content-type "page". Now, I have successfully got the "Nice Menus" module working, having created a new menu called "Default Menu" prior to that and adding only only one item called "Home" (linked to `<front>`). Thereafter, as I started creating my pages, I added it to the menu (and placing it in its rightful place in the menu hierarchy).  However, my issues are 3-fold:

1. <strike>I would very much like for the hierarchy to be followed in my URLs, which I would like to look like: **`www.mysite.com\services\counselling`**.  Furthermore, when I remove the word *`counselling`* from the URL, it should redirect me to the page for *`services`*.</strike>
2. <strike>Similar to the point above, but instead, how do I get my menu working with the breadcrumb? It stays on ***Home*** no matter which page I navigate to!</strike>
3. Lastly (this is more advice that I ask for), the first 2 links under **News** are essentially stories with either `chairman-speeches` or `community-news` as Tags. Is it possible that when a user clicks on **Chairman's Speeches** (for instance) that they can be redirected to a page that shows only stories tagged with `chairman-speeches` and similar for **Community News**?

Sorry, this is a long post, and I AM a noob to Drupal and still trying to learn the ropes. I know Drupal has a steep learning curve, and believe me - I intend to sit and understand as much of it as possible. For now though, I would really, really appreciate your help with my issues above. In advance, THANK YOU ever so much!

### EDIT:

1. I've managed to sort out my second issue of the breabcrumb-menu-linking by using the [Menu Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module...works like a charm!
2. Going back to my first point, what I aim to achieve is exactly like what is on http://amnesty.org/en/who-we-are/our-people for example...breadcrumb works, and if you delete "our-people" from the URL in the address bar, it will cause you navugate one up to the page for "who-we-are".

### EDIT 2:

Er...ok...I feel really thick for not seeing this option before, but I've sorted out my first problem also! If it helps any other noobs out there, when you create a page (and assuming you have the Path Auto module installed) you can manually set the path. So because the path for `www.mysite.com/services` already corresponds to a node, I create my child pages with the path entry: `services/counselling', and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm sorry I've only come back to this now, but just to let you know that I've sorted out issue #3 using Views....what a brilliant module! @Vilepickle, thanks for giving me a head start with using taxonomy - I was able to sort everyhting out by creating separate content types for "Chairman Speeches" and "Community News" and taxonomy terms for each respectively. Thereafter, I just used 2 Views to display all posts filtered by either `chairman-speeches` or `community-news` node-types, added a Page display, and set the menu path for each accordingly.

My reason for creating separate content-types instead of using tags, is because I wanted each of them to have their own tags under each one.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to address the third is using taxonomy.  You'll have a vocabulary setup and the terms you want to use for charmain's speeches and community news are under that vocabulary (maybe call the vocabulary "News Categories").  You can make it so your news items use this taxonomy vocabulary (optional or required) and then you'll select one (or many) when you make a new post.

Drupal will automatically create a taxonomy term page for the new terms when you have posts tagged with them.  Just get the URLs and use those as your menu path for those menu links.